# Getting domain user list in marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

After clicking Add it now button we need to display the domain users. How to display the user list in Java

Thanks

Comment: By domain users, are you referring to a Windows domain (in which case you can use LDAP to query active directory), or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for :

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/

> The Profiles Data API allows client applications to retrieve and
>   update profile information for users in a Google Apps domain. Each
>   user profile is stored in the owning user's Google Account, but it can
>   be modified only by an administrator of the user's domain.